# Python 3.9.7 Visual Studio Code; Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytorch, python-3.9

My goal is to be able to use CUDA.
For installation, I implemented below code, and got error messages.

```
pip install numpy --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --force-reinstall --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu116
```

*Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu116

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.*

Already tried all solutions on StackOverflow and Github but nothing worked.

Comment: Could you show info about the environment in which you tried this? Maybe pip list bash command. Your operating system and its version would be also good. Which virtual env (if any) you use for this command.

Comment: Hi Mert, I'm directly implementing all the codes on the visual studio code base(Python 3.9.7). It shows ~/opt/anaconda3/bin/python. pip list is too long... could you advise exactly what you would want to know? Sorry I'm not familiar with all this stuff.. Btw numpy version is 1.24.1

Comment: When you say vs code base, do you mean vscode on desktop? I asked this because there is also service provided by github, called github codespace on vscode. I am asking because there might dependency conflict. Could you give the version all torch related packages if already installed. Also, there might be conflicts between cuda-toolkit provided by torch binaries, and cuda driver version. Regarding this issues, you can check this link. https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility. The cuda setup consists of 2 main parts: cuda toolkit and driver

Comment: Hi Mert, I don't think I'm using github codespace. I'm using vscode on my laptop. Here is what I found; torch is 1.13.1, torchaudio is 0.13.1, and torchvision is 0.14.1. Also pytorch version 1.13.1, build py3.9_0 and Channel pytorch